Girl killed has the killer's ring inside her mouth
USA Thriller Movie of 90s.
The movie begins in a radio station, a man (the killer) calls live threatening or disclosing his murderous intentions.
There are some murders and a girl has a suspect... she tells this to a woman (a journalist or a detective) but she does not believe to her because the suspect seems to be a good and worthy man.
The movie ends with the killer who kills the girl, but before dying she manages to put his ring inside her mouth, so the police find the guilty party and the woman says that the girl was right.

Please try to add anything that may help identification.  Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
